# Deploying Laravel Application on Cloudways error

Tags: php, laravel, cloudways

I'm trying to deploy my local host laravel project to a live Cloudways Digitalocean server. I have done a SSH transfer from bitbucket to deploy the app but am getting the following error when I try to view the live app. Stripe is not causing any issues on the local host.

["Class 'Laravel\Cashier\CashierServiceProvider' not found"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9JYe.png)

I've also created a seperate .env file and uploaded it to the server using the server database variables. Can anyone advise if this is the correct procedure?

I've found it really difficult to find any tutorials on how to deploy a Laravel app to a live environment. If anyone has encountered this issue or could point me in the right direction to fix this error it would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you run `composer install`? (do you have `vendor/` folder in your project?)

Comment: The bitbucket push doesn't have a vendor folder. But when I look at the server files on filezilla I can see a vendor folder there. Do I run composer install from the same cmd cd directory as the local host?

Comment: in terminal (ssh) you run `composer install` from project root on your server.

Comment: did you follow any tutorial to do the setup? maybe post the link to tutorial...

Comment: This is the link to the tutorial I followed but it doesn't cover composer install or anything to do with the .env file. https://dev.to/rizwan_saquib/deploy-laravel-application-on-cloud-easily-with-cloudways

Comment: Hi, I am saquib rizwan, Laravel community manager at cloudways. I am here to help you out. Have you tried running this command? 

composer require laravel/cashier=~5.0.

Comment: If it is already installed then try running: composer update

Comment: If the issue still exists please email me.